# How to benchmark memory in an embedded linux device?

Tags: linux, storage, block-device, benchmark

Is there a generic utility to benchmark external memory device (eMMC, DDR) throughput on an embedded device (e.g. raspberry pi)? memtester, bonnie, bonnie++, memtest, dd?

I've been running into issues related to the "[infelicities](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)" of some of the `open` flags and the fact that linux caches things and was giving me extraordinary read speeds.  I ended up ditching a C app and tested 10MiB operations straight from the command line with `dd`:

#### Sequential Write Test of eMMC

`sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; time dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mydevicepartition count=20 bs=524288 conv=fsync`

#### Sequential Read Test of eMMC

`sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; time dd if=/dev/mydevicepartition of=/dev/null count=20 bs=524288`

Someone else on [this forum](http://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/linux/f/354/t/62052) seems to have had similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Linux Benchmark Suite](http://lbs.sourceforge.net/)? It includes multiple tools to measure performance on a wide range of storage formats, including disk (Memory cards, etc) and memory (RAM, L1 and L2 cache, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Using dd option oflag direct bypasses RAM caching. Using block size of the order of the eMMC erase block size (typically 4M-16M) is recommended for optimal write performance.

Choosing the right benchmark depends upon the application of your embedded device obviously.

Mobibench: https://github.com/ESOS-Lab/mobibench

IOzone: http://www.iozone.org/

dd: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html

are some frequently used applications.